# String.format fails to format numbers on some devices?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
int color = 0;
int number = 0;
// ...
s = String.format("%dproduct%d", color, number);
```

This works fine on my computer and on my Android device. I get strings like `0product0` etc.
BUT in production, on users' Android devices, I get strings like:

```
٠product٠
٠product١
٠product٢
٠product٣
٠product٤
```

Does String.format() not work OK when starting with a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings you get are "correct" for an Arabic Locale, as e.g. the UTF-8 dual-byte value `d9 a0` (as posted by Andy) encodes the Unicode code point `U+0660`, being the `ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO`.

As the rest of your output isn't locale-dependent, you probably want the numbers shown in US Locale as well, as proposed by Hitesh Sarsava:

```
String s = String.format(Locale.US, "%dproduct%d", color, number);
```

Comment: Nice one - it raises for me a new testing strategy for my app - "How does it look in various Locales" - a daunting task.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea this was a "feature" of `String.format`, to, by default, butcher numbers based on where you are in the world. Ridiculous!

Comment: It's not only in Locales with non-latin scripts, it's also the decimal  comma instead of point in Germany when using `%f`.

Comment: I knew about the coma, but this digits thingy for Hindu-Arabic... it's the first time I'm hearing about it :)

Answer (score 2):

use format like this :

```
String s = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%dproduct%d", color, number);
```

or use as per your requirement like this :

```
String s = String.format(Locale.US, "%dproduct%d", color, number);
```

Comment: I would accept your answer, as you are the first one to propose a solution, unfortunately you have not posted why my code fails. The others have posted some good explanations.

Comment: as per the Locale system the format of string changes as per the region wise. all regions have different language to support multiple format of strings. :)